# Docusign Admin Permissions Required for Legacy Offline Signing

Tags: docusignapi

I have a PA/Flow configured that uses a generic account (userY) to generate an envelope and it is assigned to a specific user (userX) to get in-person signers in an often offline scenario.

The entire process works if userX has Admin privileges but seemingly any form of alternative granular access suggested (anything in the user section including "send on behalf of other users") does not work. The user downloads the envelope, goes offline, completes the in-person signing process, gets back online and the upload process flaps and gives a permission error.

If I cut out the offline process it works without a hitch. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the [API log](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) of all the API calls. (XXX out email addresses and other private info.) Add the logs to your question by **editing** your question. And provide the actual error, not just "permission error." Finally, what to you mean by "going offline?" Disconnecting from the internet?

Comment: Turns out its a known bug apparently:
"Thank you for contacting DocuSign Developer Support, ... our engineering team had a ticket open on this behavior already for folks using the iOS Legacy DocuSign app. The app was requiring an API call that only admins could make when the device tried to update the envelopes. It looks like a hotfix was pushed for this and it should be fixed in version 1.0.3 of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the legacy iOS app that was since fixed.
This feature doesn't require admin access any longer.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ds-legacy/id1525786602
Note that this app doesn't support many new features of the iOS app for DocuSign (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/docusign-upload-sign-docs/id474990205) so we recommend you consider using the newest one.